# Transposing Data in Pandas, rows becomes columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, but i want the Attributes to be columns and the corresponding data to transpose..any ideas please as am quite stuck on this?

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing you have this DataFrame:

```py
     Attribute    Value
0  DESCRIPTION      XXX
1   Price HLDS    114.8
2  DESCRIPTION      YYY
3   Price HLDS  11.0255
```

Then:

```py
print(
    df.pivot(columns="Attribute", values="Value")
    .apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda k: pd.isna(k)))
    .dropna()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
  DESCRIPTION Price HLDS
0         XXX      114.8
1         YYY    11.0255
```